# Why do people put TabController inside initState when putting it inside Widget build does the work just fine?

Tags: flutter, dart, tabbar, provider

A lot of the tutorial I saw always put the TabController inside initState like this:
(example tutorial: [TabBar Widget in flutter](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/tabbar-widget-in-flutter-ce38f291e89f))

```
TabController _tabController;

void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
}
```

but none has explained why, when below example works just fine:

```
TabController _tabController;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  ...
}
```

Is there any advantage of putting it inside initState and not inside Widget build?

I'm asking this because I want to use provider for the TabController length and can't do it if I put TabController inside initState,
so right now what I'm doing is this:

```
TabController _tabController;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  _tabController = TabController(length: Provider.of<List>(context).listLength, vsync: this);
  ...
}
```

and I want to know if there is a known bug or whatever reason it is people put the TabController inside initState.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `initState` only runs once, when the component is created, `build` runs each time the component is rendered, so if you initialize the state inside build, you will be initializing the state everytime.

Here is an example, `BuildWidget` will change its value on each render, while `StateWidget` will only change its value on initialization.

```
class BuildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const BuildWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BuildWidgetState createState() => _BuildWidgetState();
}

class _BuildWidgetState extends State<BuildWidget> {
  final Random _random = Random();
  int _value = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _value = _random.nextInt(100);
    return Center(
      child: Text('My value is $_value'),
    );
  }
}

class StateWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const StateWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StateWidgetState createState() => _StateWidgetState();
}

class _StateWidgetState extends State<StateWidget> {
  final Random _random = Random();
  int _value = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _value = _random.nextInt(100);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('My value is $_value'),
    );
  }
}
```